# AJAX/Json Error

Tags: java, ajax, json, glassfish

I'm getting this error using eclipse and glassfish server...
This is working fine using netbeans and tomcat.. is there other way to call a servlet in glassfish?

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from
fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class
    com.ob.source.QueryService
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0
```

Ajax

```
function GetDetails(sr_no){           
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "qs",
                data: "{\"sr_no\":" +  '"' + sr_no  + "\"}",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {

                    var resultsArray =  (typeof response) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response+ ')')    : response;  
                    var data = "";
                    $("#city").empty();
                    for(var i=0; i<resultsArray.length;i++){
                        data = resultsArray[0].frontline_owner;
                    }
                    $("#city").val(data);
                }
            });             

        }
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>json</display-name>


  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>QueryService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.json.source.QueryService</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>QueryService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/qs</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Make sure that a JAR containing `org.json.JSONException` can be found in the usual classpath places (`WEB-INF/lib` most probably).

Comment: yup.. the jar file is there